# In a table with columns X and Y, is it possible to place a constraint to prevent X == Y for any one record?

Tags: sql, constraints

For example, suppose I'm modeling a football league.. I have a table of `teams` and a table of `games`. A *game* has two foreign keys, `home_team_id` and `away_team_id`. It should never be the case that, for a single game, `home_team_id` = `away_team_id` (a team cannot play against itself).

I'm a stickler for preventing bad data from entering the database.. Is it possible to add a constraint to prevent this scenario from happening?

Note that I'm asking in general, not particular to any one flavor of SQL.

Comment: Use `check` constraint: `check (X <> Y)`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d82fde22544b64c9fadab5233ecf5dd7), just change DB, the syntax is the same. Note, that it doesn't handle both nulls

Comment: @astentx thanks. I can't believe this didn't come up in my searches. Guess it's a tough thing to google for.

Comment: Note that `CHECK` is ANSI SQL, so many engines support it. The linked fiddle runs Postgres, but you can change the engine and see that most will support this exact syntax as-is. (Though, in typical fashion, MySQL 5.x accepts the syntax but cheerfully ignores the constraint, because why would you want to be notified of that... Later versions fortunately improve on this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
create table t (
  x int,
  y int,
  constraint chk1 check (x <> y)
);

insert into t (x, y) values (123, 456); -- works

insert into t (x, y) values (200, 200); -- fails
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21f573acfaccb7bed87d20891e10968d).